# What regex will aloow me to find the closest number to a word either before or after the word

Tags: r, regex

I have sentences as follows

```
"There is a 10cm length of Barrett's"
"The length of Barrett's is around 5 cm"
"The Barrett's measures 10cm in length above a 4cm hiatus hernia"
"The length of Barrett's is 5cm but the length of the dysplasia is 3cm"
```

I want to extract the length of the Barrett's as part of an ifelse statement

```
    ifelse(grepl("(\\.|^)(?=[^\\.]*cm)(?=[^\\.]*Barr)(?=[^\\.]*(of |length))[^\\.]*(\\.|$)", 
dataframe[,EndoReportColumn], perl=TRUE,ignore.case = TRUE),
stringr::str_extract(stringr::str_match(dataframe[,EndoReportColumn],"(\\.|^)(?=[^\\.]*cm)(?=[^\\.]*[Bb]arr)[^\\.]*(\\.|$)"),"\\d"),"None Found")
```

The problem I have is that the numbers extracted are not correct if there are two number in the sentence so the result I get for the sentence is:

```
10
5
4
3
```

How can I get the number that is closest (either before or after) the word Barrett in a sentence that contains both the words length and Barrett in any order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(\d+\s*\w+)[^\d\r\n]*Barret|[^\d\r\n]*Barret[^\d\r\n]*(\d+\s*\w+)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bv33Kp/1)**

With a bit of programming, you can extract the contents of Group 1/2.

**Note:**
This solution is designed keeping the provided example strings in view. Also, escape each `\` with another `\`.

```
(\\d+\\s*\\w+)[^\\d\\r\\n]*Barret|[^\\d\\r\\n]*Barret[^\\d\\r\\n]*(\\d+\\s*\\w+)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(\d+\s*\w+)` - matches 1+ digits followed by 0+ white-spaces followed by 1+ word characters to match and capture the length along with its unit in **Group 1**
- `[^\d\r\n]*Barret` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither newline nor carriage return nor a digit followed by the word `Barret`
- `|` - OR
- `[^\d\r\n]*Barret[^\d\r\n]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither newline nor carriage return nor a digit followed by the word `Barret`. This is again followed by 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither newline nor carriage return nor a digit followed by the word `Barret`.
- `(\d+\s*\w+)` - matches 1+ digits followed by 0+ white-spaces followed by 1+ word characters to match and capture the length along with its unit in **Group 2**

Comment: This won't work in R. You should escape those "patterns"

Comment: When you use lazy capturing you can reduce it to `(\d+\s*\w+).*?Barret|Barret.*?(\d+\s*\w+)`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best/shortest/fastest answer, 
but it provides the results needed and can easily be expanded when the data gets more complex..

**sample data**

```
vec <- c( "There is a 10cm length of Barrett's",
"The length of Barrett's is around 5 cm",
"The Barrett's measures 10cm in length above a 4cm hiatus hernia",
"The length of Barrett's is 5cm but the length of the dysplasia is 3cm")
```

**code**

```
library( tidyverse )

l <- lapply( vec, function(x) {
  data.frame( value = as.numeric( unlist( str_extract_all( x, "[0-9]+" ) ) ),
              position = as.numeric( unlist( gregexpr( "[0-9]+", x) ) ) )
  })
matches <- as.data.frame( data.table::rbindlist(l, idcol = "id" ) )

df <- data.frame( text = vec, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
pattern_ <-"Barrett's"

library( tidyverse )
df %>%
  mutate( id = row_number(),
          start_barrett = regexpr( pattern_, text),
          end_barrett = start_barrett + nchar( pattern_ ) ) %>%
  left_join( matches, by = "id" ) %>%
  mutate( distance = ifelse( position > start_barrett, position - end_barrett, start_barrett - position ) ) %>%
  group_by( id ) %>%
  arrange( distance ) %>%
  slice( 1L ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select( text, value )
```

**output**

```
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   text                                                                  value
#   <chr>                                                                 <dbl>
# 1 There is a 10cm length of Barrett's                                      10
# 2 The length of Barrett's is around 5 cm                                    5
# 3 The Barrett's measures 10cm in length above a 4cm hiatus hernia          10
# 4 The length of Barrett's is 5cm but the length of the dysplasia is 3cm     5
```